# Is there a way to query for a list of values belonging to a specific field in a queryset?

Tags: templating, query, elementquery

For instance, if I wanted an array of all the titles belonging to a subset of entries that I wish to query. The way I know how to do this currently is like so:

```
  {% set titleList = [] %}
  {% articleQuery = craft.entries().section('articles') %}
  {% for article in articleQuery.all() %}
    {% set titleList = titleList|merge([article.title]) %}
  {% endfor %}
```

The other way I can think of to do this operation is with the `map` twig filter, but I'm wondering if there is a way to query for such a field-value list straight away and avoid spending computational time on iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep! It's not *super* well documented, but there's a little information about it down in the [Advanced Element Queries](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html#advanced-element-queries) section of the docs. It would look something like:

```
  {% set titleList = craft.entries.section('articles').select('title').column() %}
```

One thing to note, if you're selecting a field value instead of the title, the `select` parameter will look something like `select('field_fieldHandle')`

Comment: You answered my question exactly, but in case anyone is interested in an after-the-query way to dice up their objects, the `column` filter seems like a great option because you can even pass a function for extra logic. https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html#column